# android: ListView or Activity do not update after ProgressDialog with json Data

Tags: android, listview, progressdialog

I search for day's to find my error. I do not have any success.
I have a activity with a ListView. The ListView update every 5 min with json Data. To get the json Data I POST the latitude und the longitude to my Server(filter it with sql). I clear the ListView every time. `mylist.clear();` OK. That works fine.

The LocationManager always Update the Location (I check it with a Toast). I filter the county for json Data.

```
JSONObject json = null;
           json = jsonFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://myurl.de", mlat, mlon);
```

But when I left a county and I am in a new county, then the ListView does not Update with the new Data. It shows after each upadte the old Data from the old county.

But, I have a other activity

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

in the app when I start it and come back to the activity with the ListView, the NEW county with correct json Data are available...

I did not find my mistake. Can you help me please?

The Code:

```
public class StartActivity extends ListActivity {
    private Timer autoUpdate;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GpsData gps;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.report_btn);
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        //new task().execute();
    }

     @Override
     public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      autoUpdate = new Timer();
      autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             //start GPS
             gps = new GpsData(StartActivity.this);
             Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "lat: " + gps.getLatitude() + "lon: " + gps.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             //start json download
             new task().execute();
         }
        });
       }
      }, 0, 300000); // updates each 5 min
     }

class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(StartActivity.this);
    InputStream is = null ;
    String result = "";
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       progressDialog.setMessage("Status Update...");
       progressDialog.show();
       progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
        task.this.cancel(true);
       }
    });
     }
       @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            //get Location Data
               double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
               double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
               String mlat = String.valueOf(latitude);
               String mlon = String.valueOf(longitude);

               //if (gps.latitude != 0.0) {

           JSONObject json = null;
           json = jsonFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://myurl.de", mlat, mlon);

        if (json != null){

      try{
        JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("bing");
        mylist.clear();
        String myCity = "";
            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                //get the wright name for artID
                String myArt = getString(getResources().getIdentifier("list_" + e.getString("artID"), "string", getPackageName()));

                if (!(e.getString("county") == e.getString("city"))){
                    myCity = e.getString("city");
                }

                if (e.getString("city").equals("")){
                    myCity = e.getString("county");
                }

                // Get Time difference
                String clienttime = e.getString("clienttime");
                long mTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.valueOf(clienttime).longValue()) / (60 * 1000);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("mlat", e.getString("lat"));
                map.put("mlon", e.getString("lon"));
                map.put("first", myArt + ": " + e.getString("road") + ", " + myCity);
                map.put("second", mTime + " min. ago, " + e.getString("suburb"));
                mylist.add(map);
            }       
      }

      catch(JSONException e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
      }
      }
        else{
          mylist.clear();
          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id",  "1");
            map.put("mlat", "51.6764996");
            map.put("mlon", "7.7664251");
            map.put("first", getString(R.string.no_data1));
            map.put("second", getString(R.string.no_data));
            mylist.add(map);
      }
      //}

            return null;

        }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(StartActivity.this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                new String[] { "first", "second" }, 
                new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

setListAdapter(adapter);

final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Map View is coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        //Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:" + o.get("mlat") + "," + o.get("mlon") + "?z=20"));
        //startActivity(intent);
    }
});
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        } 
    }

@Override
public void onPause() {
 super.onPause();
 autoUpdate.cancel();
 gps.stopUsingGPS();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create adapter each time in postExecute , just use adepter.clear then add new data after that call notifyDataSetChanged .

Comment: When I add mylist.notifyDataSetChanged();
I get the error: The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Comment: it is adapter class method .

Comment: You need to tell from adapter to listview that data is changed so after you have added new data replacing old call that method of ListAdapter object which should be global adapter created once.

Comment: it does not work. is it realy possible that a SimpleAdapter can update?